# Registering and Registering a .dll from code

Tags: c++, regsvr32

I am trying to register a dll from my code(Windows 7, 64-bit Application). 
The code snippet as below.

```
hinst = ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), L"regsvr32.exe", str, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
str -> fully qualified path of the file like  C:\\XXXX\\XXXX\\XXXX.dll"
```

The ShellExecute returns the following:

> "0x0000002a" and fails to register the file

What could be the issue?

Comment: As per ShellExecute documentation, it returns value greater than 0x20 on success. In your case it indeed returns value greater than 0x20, so the call to ShellExecute itself succeeds. Why do you think it does not work as expected?

Comment: The .dll dosent get registered and a window pops up saying. The module C:\XXXX\XXX failed to load blah blah . The specified module could not be found

Comment: Well, this means that regsvr32 is failing, not ShellExecute itself. Please share the actual value of `str` that causes the failure.

Comment: str  is simply a path of the .dll on my system .

Comment: Obviously, it either points to an absent file, or the path fails to be passed to regsvr32.exe properly. If you're not willing to disclose the details, I'll not be able to help you.

Comment: Str = C:\XXXX\Common\PXJSite.dll . When i tried to register directly , it gets registered without any problem

Comment: I found that problem is with space in the path (folder name). It works when the path is C:\NewFolder\Test.dll and fails when path is C:\New Folder\Test.dll . What could be the problem ?

Comment: At this point, feel free to use Google to your advantage. Also note how you've been consistently hiding your problem under XXXX, like anyone really cares of your folder structure.